# User filters in R shiny from user input csv

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to have the user upload a .csv file, then take a column (factor) of that .csv file and create user input of to determine which of the unique names in that field will be selected for the data frame.

So if I have the following example data.frame:

```
          COURSE    VALUE
      1     A        7
      2     A        9
      3     B        10
      4     C        12
    ....
```

I'd want to filter have a list of checkboxes with A, B, and C. And then the user could select say A and C and the data frame would be filtered for just rows with A and C. The portion of code below is just for trying to get  the checkboxes for the user input.

The loading of the csv file is fine. It is a reactive portion that loads into model.data0(). However, I get an error about length(0). The code below is from the server.r file and the ui.r just has a RenderU{('coose_course)}.

```
output$choose_course <- renderUI({
  # If missing input, return to avoid error later in function
  if(is.null(input$model.input))
    return()

  # Get the data set with the appropriate name
  course.names <- as.vector(unique(select_(model.data0(),"COURSE")))

  # Create the checkboxes and select them all by default
  checkboxGroupInput("courses", "Choose courses", 
                     choices  = course.names,
                     selected = course.names)
})
```

Comment: Maybe change course.names to `course.names <- unique(model.data0()$COURSE)`?

Comment: "ui.r just has a RenderU{('coose_course)}" -- you means `uiOutput('choose_course')`?

Comment: @Batanichek, yes I meant uiOutput.

Comment: @zx8754, I didn't think it liked the $ for reactive functions. Seems I needed to transpose it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "transpose"

Comment: course.names <- as.vector(t(unique(select_(model.data0(),"COURSE"))))